# Extracting images from SWF and tranparency

Tags: flash, imagemagick, ffdec

I trying to extract resource from swf animation(it is one of the resource from app)
in app that animation is tranparent, but when i extract data i got them on black background.
extracted frame:

[image: extracted frame]
in viewer image, transparent background.

[image]

(i choose that, cuz default is bad looking)

i found ffdec and it say that it is DefineBitsJPEG2 (21).
in sprite definition which don't have background i can see blendMode : UI8 = 8
i figure out how to change background(i use imagemagick compose Plus), but i can't figure out how to restore alpha channel for that i can use it without manual blending.

Any advices how i can make it?(better if with imagemagick)

Comment: I don't use ImageMagick but in Flash `blendMode : UI8 = 8` means "ADD" (similar to PhotoShop's "Colour Dodge" mode). Also `DefineBitsJPEG2` can hold PNG data (with alpha channel). For keeping alpha channel, maybe you could search a tool to extract embedded images from SWF (or read a tutorial to extract PNG direct from SWF bytes via hex editor).

Comment: ffdec allow extract all good, but there no png, by use same method i can add any BG to image.
But i can't figure out how to restore alpha if there was no blend-add mode

Comment: You see top image with back bg? Take another second copy and use a blend mode like ADD to first image. This makes the pixels have a "glow" effect. Now take another (third) image of just green colour and put over glowed image with 50% transparency. This recreates your second example image if thats what you want?

Comment: I cant understand if you mean ffdec only outputs jpegs (even if app was using png), or you mean the app actually never had png image anyways?

Comment: ffdec can output png, so second variant, looks like that image never was fully transparent.
maximum that i can achieve is to draw it on another background, or this
http://s16.postimg.org/wdgn67izl/res3.jpg

Comment: This **[image example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9JzE8.png)** shows what you could try to do if possible with ImageMagick. Basically take the original and output a greyscale copy (later you use this greyscale as a transparency mask). The bottom example part suggests how you could take original and combine it with colour background but you also use that other greyscale to control transparency of blending / masking / compositing. Maybe imageMagick can even set that greyscale as new alpha channel for PNG?